# SQL Server Query - How to Pivot this set of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I've been playing around and just not coming up with anything workable :(  I have a simple query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.DeviceUID, IP.DeviceName, d.NodeName from Devices d
    inner join IPSCHEMA IP on IP.PLCIP=d.CommunicationAddress
```

This brings me to the data I want to Pivot (Subset of that data below):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      DeviceUID      |     DeviceName   |     NodeName     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         226         |      Boiler      |      BOILER      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         226         |      Boiler      |      AMMONIA     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         226         |      Boiler      |      CHILLER     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         230         |      SSilo       |      SSUG        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         230         |      SSilo       |      WALKER      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      AMMONIA     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      BOILER      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      CAR_A       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      CAR_B       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      LINE1       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I need it to look like the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      DeviceUID      |     DeviceName   |     Node1        |      Node2       |       Node3      |       Node 4     |       Node5      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         226         |      Boiler      |      BOILER      |     AMMONIA      |     CHILLER      |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         230         |      SSilo       |      SSUG        |     WALKER       |                  |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         29          |      Cooling     |      AMMONIA     |     BOILER       |     CAR_A        |       CAR_B      |       LINE1      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I'm sure I can export to Excel, modify, make it look like that.  But I would like this to be a repeatable Stored Procedure I can use for the current dataset.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure there will be some replies soon that point out something like *dynamic SQL*, but I am interested in where this can be useful. What application with a standard way to handle results will be able to process resultsets with an unpredictible set of columns? For me, it only makes sense for some kind of "Report", and yes, SSRS Reports are able to take your source query and produce such a pivoted result. I would rather export to Excel than use a dynamical query assembling in a stored procedure of a relational database management system. What do you think?

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of nodes?  If so, you can easily `pivot` the data.  If not, you still can, you'll just need to use `dynamic sql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but we just add a PIVOT to your initial query.

This also assumes you have a known or maximum number of nodes.  If not, you would have to go DYNAMIC.

```
Select *
 From  ( 
        Select *
              ,Item = concat('Node',Row_Number() over (Partition By DeviceUID,DeviceName Order by (Select null))
         From (
                SELECT DISTINCT IP.DeviceUID, IP.DeviceName, d.NodeName from Devices d
                 inner join IPSCHEMA IP on IP.PLCIP=d.CommunicationAddress
              ) A
       ) src
 Pivot (max(NodeName) for Item in ([Node1],[Node2],[Node3],[Node4],[Node5]) ) pvt
```

Comment: Perfect!  I had to add an ending ) after the Select null and added a few more Node fields - but exactly what I was after, thank you!!

Comment: @Andrew Happy to help and pleased you corrected my mistake.